# How to permanently upload files onto Google Colab such that it can be directly accessed by multiple people?

Tags: google-colaboratory

My friend and I are working on a project together on Google Colab for which we require a dataset but we keep running into the same problem while uploading it.

What we're doing right now is uploading onto drive and giving each other access and then mounting gdrive each time. This becomes time consuming and irritating as we need to authorize and mount each time.

Is there a better way so that the we can upload the dataset to the home directory and directly access it each time? Or is that not possible because we're assessed a different machine(?) each time?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new notebook, you can set it to mount automatically, no need to authenticate every time.

See [this demo](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1226929213560610818?s=20).